# How do proxy sites like hidemyass get Google to load in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

Websites like hidemyass.com manage to load Google and Twitter even despite the "X-Frame-Options : SAMEORIGIN".
Any idea how do they do that?

Comment: HideMyAss.com doesn't use iframes. It's a proxy.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on the wrong assumption that HMA uses iframes to load content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don´t load the website into an iframe.

On the background, the website downloads the sourcecode from Google; and then renders it inside their own code.